# Render Error in React Native for Component Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and react native and am trying to pass values received from an api down to child components.
The initial component is use is this

```
<ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        className="p-2"
      >
        {technicianListings?.map(technician => (
          <TechnicianCard 
            key={technician.id.toString()}
            id={technician.id}
            personal_info={technician.autouser}
            region={technician.region}
            rating={technician.rating}
            profile_pic={technician.autouser.photo}
            description={technician.shop_description}
            shop_motto={technician.shop_goal}
            skill_badge={technician.skill_badge}
            reviews={technician.technician_feedback}  
            specializatons={technician.technician_specialization} 
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
```

I am checking if the API data has loaded before rendering this part works beautifully without a problem.
The technician card looks like this

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { MapPinIcon, TrophyIcon } from 'react-native-heroicons/solid'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'


const TechnicianCard = ({
  id,
  personal_info,
  region,
  rating,
  profile_pic,
  description,
  shop_motto,
  skill_badge,
  reviews,
  specializations
}) => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
        className="bg-amber-100 p-3 mb-2 rounded-lg"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('TechnicianProfile', {
            id,
            region,
            rating,
            profile_pic,
            description,
            shop_motto,
            skill_badge,
            reviews,
            specializations,
          });
        }}
    >   
      {/* Technician Performance Rank */}
      <View className="flex-row-reverse mb-5" >
        <TrophyIcon size={20} color="black"/>
        <TrophyIcon size={20} color="black"/>
      </View>

      {/* Technician Personal Information */}
      <View>
        {/* Technician Name */}
        <Text className="text-lg tracking-tight pb-2">{personal_info.first_name + ' ' + personal_info.last_name}</Text>
        <View>
          {/* Location Information */}
          <View className="flex-row">
            <MapPinIcon size={16} color="black"/>
            <Text>{region}</Text>
          </View>

          {/* Rating Information */}
          <View className="flex-row">
            <Text className="italic font-bold">Rating </Text>
            <Text> {rating}/5</Text>
          </View>

          <Image
          source={{
            uri: profile_pic,
          }}  

          className=" h-10 w-10 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full absolute bottom-0 right-0"
        />
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default TechnicianCard
```

Once I touch the card to navigate me to the next screen react native throws a render error that states

```
TypeError: personal_info is undefined

This error is located at:
    in TechnicianCard (created by TechnicianProfile)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by TechnicianProfile)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by TechnicianProfile)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in NativeWind.View
    in Unknown (created by TechnicianProfile)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by TechnicianProfile)
    in TechnicianProfile (created by SceneView
```

What am I doing wrong, when I console log al the information is present but React Native doesn't render it.

Comment: What is the value of `technician.autouser`, or more generally, the value of `technicianListings` that is mapped? It appears that `personal_info` is undefined for at least one mapped element. The `TechnicianCard` component should account for potentially undefined prop values.

Comment: @DrewReese technician.autouser is an object, none of the objects being mapped is empty.

Comment: Did you put in `console.log` in `TechnicianCard`? I think @DrewReese right. An item in `autouser` is missing a `personal_info` field.

Comment: Think you could edit the post to include enough code to be considered a [mcve]? Could you also try making a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?